# Is this a known formula for computation of Riemann Zeta function for even integers?

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion, riemann-zeta

$$\zeta(2n) = \frac{\pi^{2n}}{4^n-1}\space\cdot\space\frac{n}{(2n)!}\cdot\frac{d}{dx^{2n}}\bigg[\ln\big(\sec(x)\big)\bigg]_{x\space=\space0}$$

I found a link between the Riemann Zeta function and the Maclaurin series of $\ln(\sec(x))$, and generalized it to create the above formula. Although the formula is very similar to the one given on Wikipedia which has the Bernoulli Coefficients in it, from what I could find on the internet, computation of Bernoulli coefficients by hand is a rather tedious task, as it requires the computation of a limit at $x=0$ every time. But here, $\ln(\sec(x))$ avoids that. This might not be revolutionary, but if one were to compute the value of say, $\zeta(12)$, from scratch, I would definitely prefer to go with this method of utilising the Maclaurin series of $\ln(\sec(x))$.

Comment: The Bernoulli numbers have a nice recurrence and some explicit formulas (as a double sum). See
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_number#Recursive_definition

Comment: Since the Riemann function was so well studied, it possible that it was obtained before. But it's always fun to find formulas on your own, and you should feel good about it. Maybe the next one will be something totally new. Keep up the good work!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\frac{d}{dx^{2n}}\bigg[\ln\big(\sec(x)\big)\bigg]_{x\space=\space0}$$

seems to correspond to [A000182 Tangent (or "Zag") numbers](https://oeis.org/A000182) in which case

$$\frac{d}{dx^{2n}}\bigg[\ln\big(\sec(x)\big)\bigg]_{x\space=\space0}=(-4)^n \left(4^n-1\right) \zeta(1-2 n)\ ,$$

and it is true that

$$\zeta(2 n)=\frac{\pi^{2 n}}{\left(4^n-1\right)} \frac{n}{(2 n)!}(-4)^n \left(4^n-1\right) \zeta (1-2 n)\ .$$